# JQuery accordion - targeting only header anchors

Tags: jquery

I’ve created a Jquery accordion using this generator -
http://code.anotherwebstorm.com/apps/awsaccordion/

However, there are links within the content areas of my accordion tabs, and when these links are clicked, the tab automatically closes. I need for the tab to remain open when these content links are clicked. Only when the tab header is clicked should the tab close. The creator of this script  no longer supports it, but gave me an idea of what needs to be done, which is here:

“I think that what you need is to get into the core and change it in order to only listen to anchor tabs when clicking and not to the ones inside. I think that the key is here https://github.com/anotherwebstorm/awsAccordion/blob/master/jquery.accordion.js#L55 in this line.

All the click events are bound to headLis so if you do a couple of conditionals and / or target only the header anchors it should fix it. “

Unfortunately, I don’t know how to implement what he has described. Any help with this is much appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
headLis = elem.children().children()
```

This is where your all elements are getting initialized; now before the click event binding happens over elements of this array you can remove the elements from that array by doing your custom check

```
headLis = elem.children().children()


$headLis.each(function(){

   if(your custom check for link to be removed)
    // remove element 
})
```

check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmkooty1/3/)  for example. Please check comments

Comment: Can you provide the code on how to do that? I am new to JQuery.
Thank you!